# laser scan topic

Tags: ros, laser, scan, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i install ros indigo desktop full and Turtlebot2 Ubuntu Package .
when i do `$rostopic list` i cant find `/laser/scan` topic .
there's something like additional installation or other name of laser scan topic ?

listed topics :

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/points
/camera/parameter_descriptions
/camera/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/clock
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/switch
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
/depthimage_to_laserscan/parameter_descriptions
/depthimage_to_laserscan/parameter_updates
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/joint_states
/laserscan_nodelet_manager/bond
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
/mobile_base/events/bumper
/mobile_base/events/cliff
/mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
/mobile_base/sensors/core
/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager/bond
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/tf_static
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285686/laser-scan-topic/) by [EGYRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33719/egyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello EGYRos,

although I am not familiar with the Turtlebot2 Ubuntu Package (maybe you are referring to the turtlebot ROS package?) and cannot find the package named turtlebot2 I would like to point out that **there is a** ***/scan*** topic on your list.
Try:

```
rostopic info /scan
```

I am guessing you will find that messages being passed in this topic are of type **sensor_msgs/LaserScan**.
If you look at the [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) package you will find that it publishes laser scan on topic ***/scan***.
If you would like your laser scan to be published on another topic, you can remap it:

```
rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan scan:=laser/scan
```

However, that would be a **quick fix**. I am guessing that ***/laser*** prefix is here because of the laser namespace and maybe it would be better practice to include is as a namespace tag in your launch file. An example of setting namespace in launch file can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#Example_.launch_XML_Config_Files).

Furthermore, I can see you are using RGBD camera and depthimage_to_laserscan package to obtain laser scan like measurements.
Just a heads up, **depthimage_to_laserscan is a lazy subscriber** meaning it won't subscribe to a camera image topic and camera info topic unless there are no subscribers to ***/scan*** topic. The easiest way to ensure that there is a subscriber is to simply visualize it in rviz.

If you have any further question, feel free to ask it.

---

Originally posted by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) with karma: 516 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EGYRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33719/egyros/) on 2018-03-18**:
Hello dljubic

Ya i get it , thanks a lot it is very useful.

**Comment by [dljubic](https://answers.ros.org/users/32791/dljubic/) on 2018-03-19**:
No problem, I am glad to help! :)
Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.